# Like is being sent to only first post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hello guys I have been working on a website, kind of social media I guess. But going specific to the problem, I have a index page where I outputted all the post from the table `posts`, I used the while loop as usual. For checking purpose i added a input which has the post id with the button. when the button is clicked AJAX performs a request and transfers that data to a file called addlike.php. and the addlike.php echoes back the post_id.
So the problem occurs right here, I have 2 posts, having id 1 and 2. but when I click the second posts submit button, the addlike.php returns back the id of first post.
my form

```
<form method="POST" id="frmBox" onsubmit="return addlikejs()">
                                       <div class="job-status-bar">

                                          <ul class="like-com">
                                             <h3 id="s"></h3>
                                                <li>
                                                   <a href="#" onclick="addlike()" name="check"><i class="la la-heart"></i> Like</a>
                                                   <img src="images/liked-img.png" alt="">
                                                   <span style="color:white;"><?php echo $post['likes']; ?></span>
                                                </li>
                                                <li><a href="#" title="" class="com"><img src="images/com.png" alt=""> <?php echo $post['comments']; ?></a></li>

                                          </ul>
                                          <!--
                                             <a><i class="la la-eye"></i>Views 50</a>
                                             -->
                                       </div>
                                       <input name="post"  id="post-id" value="<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>">
                                       <input type="submit" name="like" onclick="sendlike();">
                                   </form>
```

My Jquery :

```
function sendlike(){
    alert($('#post-id').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/_assets/addlike.php',
        data: $('#frmBox').serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }
    })
}
```

MY addlike.php

```
<?php
require('function.php');
global $con;
$send_like = $_POST['post'];
echo $send_like;

?>
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @tadman so can I make strong applications using light weight frame work?

Comment: You should paste whole code of that functionality...
Look that, you have `sendlike` method called on submit button, `addlikejs` on whole form  submit.
It's hard to understand what happened there :(

Comment: Light or full-featured is more a matter of preference than applicability. Just keep in mind the lighter the framework is, the more you're responsible for making decisions and implementing details. Whatever framework you choose, though, you'll be working with code familiar to others, which makes getting help easier.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using your while loop , does it include `<form>` or its just for the posts. If it does than you have multiple same IDs. This needs to be unique.

You need to choose a unique id for each form or set class attribute to form.
i.e

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" class="frmBox" onsubmit="return addlikejs()">
```

and then your jQuery:

```
function sendlike(){
alert($('#post-id').val());

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/_assets/addlike.php',
    data: $('.frmBox').serialize(),
    success: function(response)
    {
        alert(response);
    }
})
```

Hope this help :-)

Comment: Now its returning '2' always